# Linear voltage regulator current

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

I am planning to modify a 18.5V 3500mAh DC laptop power supply to a max 6V DC with a linear voltage regulator like the L7805 with 2x 10uF capacitor and 1 x 0.1uF capacitor. My question is...Can this linear regulator handle that current with a big enough heat sink and how big is big. Or will it all just come melting down. The current must obviously stay as high as possible without to much losses.

Thanks

Comment: Read the fine datasheet

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to load your 5 V supply with less than 200 mA or so then a 10cm x 10 cm heatsink should suffice (I just sucked that out of my thumb, I'm too lazy to do a proper calculation).

If you need mode current then FORGET about using a linear regulator, the heat dissipation will be a problem and there is no need for that, just get a switched mode regulator module: [like this one](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/Big-Current-5A-DC-DC-Adjustable-BUCK-Step-Down-Module-Effect-Higher-Than-LM2596-/191095481150?hash=item2c7e2da33e:g:2kkAAOxyBotTYMpR) or a more luxurious one like [this one](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/DC-Buck-75W-Converter-Power-Supply-Module-4-0-38V-to-1-25V-35V-5A-MAX-Voltmeter-/161762294834?hash=item25a9c8bc32:g:zuQAAOSwDNdVo4JO).